# BDD: Is it wrong to call it "Behaviour Driven *Design*"?

Tags: bdd

I learned the concept of BDD in [this nice book](http://www.saasbook.info/), where the authors continuously refer to it as *Behavior Driven **Design***, rather than using the term "Development". I've been using this definition since then (and it makes sense for me, especially when combined with a Test-Driven **Development** cycle). However, after presenting the concept of BDD to a colleague, he googled it and found out that most of the references call it "Behavior Driven Development".

Is there a difference between the two definitions? Should I call it *Behavior-Driven Development*, even if some relevant sources use the other translation?

Comment: Does BDD help you design something? If so call it design if you want.

Comment: IIRC "Behavior Driven Design" is somewhat different from "Behavior driven development"....

Comment: DDD = Domain Driven *Design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan North and others did refer to it as Behaviour-Driven Design back in the early days, when JBehave was just a replacement for JUnit.

However, when it moved up the stack to the system level, with examples that described the behaviour of entire applications rather than just individual classes, it became apparent that it affected more than just the design, and we started calling it Behaviour-Driven Development.

So, Development is now correct, and Design is old and out-of-date. You could feasibly think of Behaviour-Driven Design practices as a subset of Behaviour-Driven Development.

Comment: That's unfortunate, since it's primarily a *design technique, not a programming technique.*  The same is true of TDD, which has the unfortunate moniker "Test-Driven *Development.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Development" in this sense refers to the entire software development lifecycle. Otherwise we'd have called it Behaviour-Driven Programming.

Comment: Well, all right.  But most inexperienced folks read "programming" and "development" as the same thing, and see design as architecture.  xDD is mostly about the latter, not the former.

Comment: Most inexperienced *developers* might, but it's their role that's poorly titled, since they're usually coders or programmers. I can promise that testers and analysts don't make that assumption, nor does the Head of Development in your org, and it's that person we're really trying to sell it to.

Comment: All the more reason to not hang your hat on a *word.*  It's kind of like telling a joke; *if you have to explain it,* it's not funny anymore.

Comment: One can make a good case that programming is design at a low level of abstraction (the lowest before automation takes over) and architecture is design at a high level of abstraction. BDD appears to include a significant requirements-gathering component, in which case it would be more appropriate to think of it as a development technique.

Comment: @RobertHarvey We care a lot more about the results than we do about what people call it. So I wouldn't worry too much. My hat is hanging over here: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Learning-and-Perverse-Incentives